# Error : "javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load test suite [SampleTest], Reason is [Class not found "SampleTest"] "

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, cactus

Hi i am new to cactus and when i am using tomcat5.1 and have included all the necessary jars. But when i am trying to execute it, it is showing the error,

Error : "javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load test suite [SampleTest], Reason is [Class not found "SampleTest"] "

Please let me know what the problem is??

Comment: You're going to have to give more details on how you're deploying the app, running tomcat etc etc...

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm having the same problem.  I posted a workaround I was able to come up with.  Not a very good one though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run the **Quick Start tutorial** from the Cactus web site, I believe it no longer works.

Here's a mention in the release notes of 1.8.1.

```
    Release Notes - Cactus - Version 1.8.1

    Bug

    * [CACTUS-124] - Cannot run the Servlet Example
```

I get the same error message with version 1.7.x.

I just started researching this product, so I'll post an answer if I find one.  Hopefully someone else will have an answer with the extra info I have provided.

**EDIT:**
Found a work around.  Looks like it's an issue with package names.  I re-compiled the two files using the default/no package and it worked.

**EDIT 2:**
I looked up CACTUS-124 in the bug database and it's not related.  Also I believe only the class files that extend **ServletTestCase** need to be changed to the default/no package name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the package ie:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/ServletTestRunner?suite=common.TestEverything

Would run the suite TestEverything in the common package.

Comment: I looked into Cactus a bit more, finally, and found your solution to work.  Better then my solution. :)  so Thanks!